# Función que convierta un array a mayúsculas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vscode

Función que convierta un Array a mayúsculas usando el `for` en JavaScript? (Soy novato).

```
let peliculas = ["star wars", "totoro",  "rocky", "pulp fiction",  "la vida es bella"]

function convertirAMayusculas(peliculas) {
    for (let i = 0; i < peliculas.lenght; i++) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Especifica el lenguaje de programacion

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo, ahi lo puse gracias por tomarte el tiempo de verlo

Comment: Echale un ojo al método [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) de **javascript**

Comment: Muchas gracias Josbert! estaba haciendolo igual me faltaba la linea antes del console.log muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que usar `.toUpperCase()` para convertir a mayúsculas cada elemento del array `peliculas`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let peliculas = ["star wars", "totoro",  "rocky", "pulp fiction",  "la vida es bella"]

function convertirAMayusculas(peliculas) {
    
     for (let i = 0; i < peliculas.length; i++) {        
        peliculas[i]  = peliculas[i].toUpperCase()   
     }

    return peliculas
}

peliculas = convertirAMayusculas(peliculas)

console.log(peliculas)
```